# ldconfig does not include libs in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libraries, ldconfig

I need to use `swrast_dri.so` for Flutter but ldconfig is not locating it nor than others libs in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Here my `x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` file:

```
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

My `ld.so.conf` file:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

`swrast_dri.so` is under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/`

Here a little part of `ldconfig -p`:

```
    libGLX.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0
    libGLU.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
    libGLEW.so.2.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.1
    libGLESv2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libFLAC.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8
    libEGL_mesa.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libDeployPkg.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libDeployPkg.so.0
    libCoinUtils.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCoinUtils.so.3
    libCoinMP.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCoinMP.so.1
    libClpSolver.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libClpSolver.so.1
    libClp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libClp.so.1
    libCgl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCgl.so.1
    libCbcSolver.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCbcSolver.so.3
    libCbc.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCbc.so.3
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, Système d'exploitation ABI : Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale.so.1
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 (libc6, Système d'exploitation ABI : Linux 3.2.0) => /lib32/libBrokenLocale.so.1
    libBrokenLocale.so (libc6,x86-64, Système d'exploitation ABI : Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale.so
    ld-linux.so.2 (ELF) => /usr/lib/ld-linux.so.2
    ld-linux.so.2 (ELF) => /lib32/ld-linux.so.2
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

As you can see I don't get any libs from `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

I already tried to delete `ld.so.cache` file and rebuild it with `ldconfig` command but it didn't change anything...

([Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76178) why I need `swrast_dri.so`)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when installing ffplay from source on a RHEL 7 system in the past. What I ended up having to do for reasons still unknown was add `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` to my `/etc/ld.so.conf` file.

Full file ended up looking like this:

```
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

Once I added that in running an `ldconfig` picked up the `ffplay.conf` file I had placed in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`

Maybe the same will work for you.

Comment: Thanks but no it didn't work.